# Pandas DataFrame: create a column, with logical condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If result is not 'C' or 'V' = Top row. How to solve this?

```
df.loc[:, 'posicao'] = np.where(((df['Ordem']!=0) & (df['Tendencia'] == 1)), 'C',(df['posicao'].shift(1)))
df.loc[:, 'posicao'] = np.where(((df['Ordem']!=0) & (df['Tendencia'] == -1)), 'V', df.loc[:, 'posicao'])
```

[image: Sample Data and code]

Comment: Where is the column `df['posicao']` ?

Comment: is the column being created

Comment: You're using before create `df['posicao'].shift(1)` ?

Comment: yes, I would like the result to be C or V, if not: repeat the line above